# Error getting bitcoin block to process from DB

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, linux, ubuntu, stellar

i am installing a full node on a linux server  and i'm trying to connect to bitcoin with BIFROST(https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/bifrost) but i am getting the error below which looks like a bitcoin error. All blocks have been downloaded. Please someone should guide me. Thanks

Error getting bitcoin block to process from DB: Error getting `bitcoin_last_block` from DB: get failed: get failed: pq: relation "key_value_store" does not exist  pid=65548 service=BitcoinListener
ERRO[2018-01-05T18:42:41Z] Error starting the server                     err="Error starting BitcoinListener: Error getting bitcoin block to process from DB: Error getting `bitcoin_last_block` from DB: get failed: get failed: pq: relation "key_value_store" does not exist" pid=65548

Answer (score 0):

I had problems like this too and through hours of trial and error, I got it working, Check out my bitcoin and bifrost settings found in repositories here

https://github.com/StellarKit

I can't remember the exact problem, I think I remember I had my rpc urls wrong.

BIFROST_BITCOIN_RPC_SERVER:         "bitcoind:18332"

bitcoind refers to the bitcoin docker image and uses dockers networking.

But look at the docker-compose.yml files for a working example.

You can install everything I have to get bifrost working on testnet.